# How to write a regex pattern to extract the location from AMT withdrawal Transactions in a bank statement

Tags: r, regex, pattern-matching

I wish to write a regex pattern to extract the address or location from a string of narration for the data of 350k records.

```
txn_add <- data.frame(NARRATION=c("$ $ $ +YBL PATAUDI CHOWK \ $",
                  "$ $ -ATM CASH 83181 + MAIN BHAWANA ROAD NEW DELHI $",
                  "$ $ [5839/P1TNDE06/+RAGHUBARPURA $",
                  "$ MAXIMUMOUTFITS PRIVATE LIMITED } $ ATDELHIIN- $ $ /5631 $",
                  "$ ATM CASH-N4077800-+SPRINGFIELDCOLONYFFAR IDABADHRIN-04/06/18 $ /5631 ( $ $ VERIFICATION $"))
```

I ran the following regex pattern:

```
gsub(".*[:|+]([^.]+)[$|\\|\\/].*", "\\1", txn_add$NARRATION)
```

And i got the output as :

```
[1] "YBL PATAUDI CHOWK  "                                                  
[2] " MAIN BHAWANA ROAD NEW DELHI "                                        
[3] "RAGHUBARPURA "                                                        
[4] "$ MAXIMUMOUTFITS PRIVATE LIMITED } $ ATDELHIIN- $ $ /5631 $"          
[5] "SPRINGFIELDCOLONYFFAR IDABADHRIN-04/06/18 $ /5631 ( $ $ VERIFICATION "
```

This output is not correct as I have to implement some conditions:
Address can start from :

```
1. '+'
2. '@'
3. ' AT '
4. ':'
5. <P|S><SBI><P|S>              # EXACT TEXT PRECEEDED AND FOLLOWED BY PUNCTUATION OR SPACE
6. <NNN> FOLLOWED BY <P|S|A>    # 3 NUMBERS FOLLOWED BY EITHER PUNCTUATION OR SPACE OR ALPHA
```

And End with :

```
1. -
2. / 
3. $
4. \
5.<NNNNNNN>     # Combination of numbers
```

CAN CONTAIN

```
Alphabets, numbers, dot (.), dash (-),space ( ), coma(,),underscore (_) brackets(()) at (@), hash (#) and(&) semi colon (;)
```

This is to extract the address from the transaction & Desired Output will be:

```
[1] "YBL PATAUDI CHOWK"                                                  
[2] "MAIN BHAWANA ROAD NEW DELHI "                                        
[3] "RAGHUBARPURA "                                                        
[4] "DELHIIN"          
[5] "SPRINGFIELDCOLONYFFAR IDABADHRIN"
```

I am not able to get the desired output. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

You might use a capture group

```
(?:[+@:]|\bAT(?!M))\s*([A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[+@:]` Match one of `+` `@` `:`
  - `|` Or
  - `\bAT(?!M)` Match AT not followed by `M`
- `)` Close group
- `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace chars
- `(`  Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*` Match chars A-Z with 1+ whitespace chars in between
- `)` Close group 1

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PSoJ7y/1)

With sub matching all before and after the group:

```
sub(".*(?:[+@:]|\\bAT(?!M))\\s*([A-Z]+(?:\\s+[A-Z]+)*).*", "\\1", txn_add$NARRATION, perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks sir, this running fine for some of the cases but its is not able to handle some of the cases like : "$ USHAHIGHWAYFILLINGSFARIDABADIN-23/08 /18 $ /5631 (Ref# $ VERIFICATION $", for this the desired output is " USHAHIGHWAYFILLINGSFARIDABADIN"

Comment: @PiyushSharma Try it like this `.*?(?|(?:[+@:]| AT(?!M\b))\s*([A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*)|\b([A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*)-\d).*` See https://ideone.com/fKlnyN